# Url redirect from one to another url using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, friendly-url

Currently this is in my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /dev/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dev/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when ever user enters this url `http://test-site.com`  should redirect to `http://test-site.com/dev/`
Could any one please help me in this regard?

Comment: Where is your `.htaccess` file? Do you have any more `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? To clarify, `/dev` should be in the visible URL? What should happen to other requests in the root, eg. `/foo`?

Comment: btw. `RewriteBase /dev/` isn't doing anything in this code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your shown samples, attempts, please try following htaccess rules file. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs. I have also put comments before new rule and before a small fix in existing rule.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
##adding new rule for redirection here...
RewriteRule ^/?$ /dev? [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /dev/
##Added NC flag here for ignore case.
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /dev/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: HI, thank you, I tried with above change, But I am getting "Forbidden you don't have permission to access this resource".

Comment: @user3408779, ok, could you please try my edited rules once? Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.